# Invalid Identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to understand where the invalid identifier error is occurring  in my SQL code.  Output states, "error at command line: 9 column: 10" which is after the "on" function under the "join" function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
select
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC("SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM'), 'MON') as month,
   cast (avg("DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."value") as int) as "PAST_VALUE" 
from
   "TEST"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA",
   "TEST"."COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA" 
   join
      "TEST"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" 
      on "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" = "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID" 
where
   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" = 'ready_go' 
   and "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_SITE_ID" = ('abc123')
   and "SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_UPLOAD_TIME" between TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS ('01-MAR-17', - 13), 'MM') and TRUNC (LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS ('31-MAR-17', - 1)) + 1) 
group by
   TRUNC("SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM'),
   "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_SITE_ID" 
order by
   TRUNC("SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM') desc;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit proper `JOIN` syntax.  That is the root of your problem.

Comment: Does it matter that I am doing this in Oracle BI Publisher?  I know Oracle BI Publisher has a goofy SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your posted query you should have two `JOIN` whereas you are specifying only one `JOIN ON` condition

```
from
   "TEST"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"
   JOIN "TEST"."COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA" ON <some_condition>
   join
      "TEST"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" 
      on "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" = "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"
```

Comment: @Fadiddy, then consider doing a `left join` instead of `inner join`